Starting the orchestration funciton takes delay when returning value from activity function
i used the Orchestration function and Activity trigger in my script
[Function("MainOrchestration")]

 public async Task MainOrchestration([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context) {

        ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger("MainOrchestration");

        foreach (BasicAssetDetails assetType in CommunicationType){

         initialResult = await context.CallActivityAsync<AssetMappedDetails>("InitialAsset", assetType); }
}

and my activity function
   [Function("InitialAsset")]

    public async Task<AssetMappedDetails> InitialAsset([ActivityTrigger] BasicAssetDetails AssetDetails, FunctionContext executionContext){...}

when the forloop calls the acitivity ,the activity return some values , on that time MainOrchestration start with 1 or few second delay , but the activity complete execution.
i dont know why the Orchestration take few seconds to start, i know the orchestration will be rehydrated , but it make the function app completion very delay
solution to make the orchestration starting time without delay,
how to stop the rehydrated
